# I can not use a C# class in a .razor page, in a blazor server application

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a small blazor server application.

Under `Data` folder, I have created `Author.cs` file, which contains a C# class. This is the code of `Author.cs` file :

```
using System;

namespace BlazorApp1.Data
{
    public class Author
    {
        public Author(string id, string fn, string ln,
            string ph, string city)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = fn;
            this.lastName = ln;
            this.phoneNumber = ph;
            this.city = city;
        }

        public string id { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string firstName { get; set; }

        public string lastName { get; set; }

        public string city { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also, under `Pages` folder, I have created `Authors.razor` file. This is the code of `Authors.razor` file :

```
@page "/authors"
@inject NavigationManager NM

<h3>Authors</h3>
<hr />

<div class="col-12">
    @foreach (Author author in AuthorList)
    {
        <div class="col-12 row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <NavLink href=@string.Format("authors/authordetails/{0}", @author.id)>
                    @author.id
                </NavLink>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">@author.firstName @author.lastName </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    public List<Author> AuthorList { get; set; }
    public AuthorService authorService { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        authorService = new AuthorService();
        AuthorList = authorService.GetAuthors();
    }
}
```

The problem is, in `foreach` loop, `Author` is underlined in red, and Visual Studio 2019 says:

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Author' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What should I do so I can use `Author` class in this .razor page?

Comment: I haven't worked with Blazor, but if it's anything like Razor, you are missing a `@using BlazorApp1.Data` at the top

Comment: Yes, It works correctly, thanks for your comment, +1.

Comment: @XYyou can also add the using statement to _Imports.razor.

Comment: @Orak Did you mean I can add it to _Imports.razor, instead of adding it to each .razor page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a namespace BlazorApp1.Data in the Component.